# Asp.net core: Is it a good idea to use tag helpers to generate search results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm updating my application that was developed using .net framework. To generate the search results I used html helpers. The search result that I mean is like a search on Youtube that includes the Image, some description text and one or two links. Now that html helpers were depricated in asp.net I am wandering If I should implement this functionality as tag helpers. I used html helpers because the requerement to display search results is found in many places in my site. The drawback is that my tag helper used several lines of code as required by the TagBuilder class for example.

```
     TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("select");
        tag.MergeAttribute("id", "ddlBrands");
        tag.MergeAttribute("name", "BrandId");
        tag.MergeAttribute("class", "form-control");
       //code to add to a container
```

5 lines of code is required to set only one element if I have ten I will end up with a helper with 50 lines of code. I can't use routing feature as effectively as I can on a view. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what a tag helper is in mvc-core. What you have shown is a `TagBuilder`, not a tag helper. Refer [Introduction to using tag helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms). And `HtmlHelper` methods have not been deprecated!

Comment: I know what a tag helper is,. I' just showed how I used html helpers to build a reusable chunk of html, which involved using the TagBuilder class which requires lines and more lines of code to generate a single html element. I think that my question was pretty clear. After revisiting an asp mvc book, I decided that using partial views is a better solution for many problems that I originally solved using Html Helpers. And Yes, Html Helpers weren't deprecated, my bad!. Tag Helpers are improved version of the still present html helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use html helpers.

I would not use c# code to generate HTML. I would use *html to create html*. I would pass model to view and use Razor.

Another solution is to use some [javascript templating engines](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/)

Third solution, which I use recently is React.js with combination with [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/) if you want SEO friendly website.

Comment: Yeah another added benefit of using templates with an ajax request is that the client will be able to cache the HTML pages better so there will be less traffic

Comment: If I use a strongly  typed partial view inside a foreach loop to iterate the search result  in  the main view is a better solution?